# Определение длины строки в С и С++

Tags: c, c++

В чем различие двух следующих записей?

```
len1 = sizeof( buffer);
len2 = strlen( buffer);
```

Какие плюсы и минусы использования? Что быстрее и где лучше применять тот или иной вариант?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Главное различие в том, что функция [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) вычисляет длину строки, а оператор [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) к вычислению длины строки никакого отношения не имеет. Оператор `sizeof` используется для определения размера памяти занимаемой сущностью. При работе со строками он может быть применим только к строкам, определенным на стеке и константным строкам. Механизм работы можно увидеть на примере:

```
char *pStr = "string";
char str[20];

strcpy(str, pStr);

int len1 = strlen(pStr);       // = 6
int len2 = strlen(str);        // = 6
int len3 = sizeof(pStr);       // = 4, если используется 32-х битная система
int len4 = sizeof(str);        // = 20
int len5 = sizeof("string");   // = 7
```

Answer (score 6):

`sizeof` - это оператор языка, применяемый для определения размера типа данных в байтах. Значение выражения с использованием `sizeof` определяется во время компиляции кода, за исключением ряда случаев, например, для массивов переменной длины, определенных в C99.

`strlen` - это функция стандартной библиотеки C, применяемая для определения длины строки, оканчивающейся нулем. Значение выражения с использованием вызова `strlen` определяется во время выполнения кода.

Answer (score 2):

Обращу внимание, что sizeof возвращает размер объекта в байтах. Т.е. обычно это максимальная длина строки, которая влезает в массив char'ов.

strlen - это функция стандартной библиотеки для определения длины 0-terminated строки. 
Возвращает кол-во символов без терминирующего 0. Т.е. реально занимаемый в памяти объем строки равен как минимум результату выполнения strlen + 1 байт.

Реально проблемы обычно возникают при работе с Юникодом, т.е. с типами wchar или TCHAR и соответствующими ф-циями. Потому что юникодовские символы занимают не 1 байт, а 2. И поэтому смешивать кол-во символов и размер их в памяти, получается, уже не стоит. А учитывая, что многие программы рано или поздно придется переделывать - лучше сразу заложить возможность для этого. Т.е. итого - запоминаем, что ф-ции работы со строками обычно требуют размер (или макс. размер) строки в символах, а ф-ции работы с памятью - обычно в байтах.

Для определения максимального кол-ва элементов (т.е. символов в строке) под MSVC я использовал макрос [_countof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175773(v=vs.80).aspx). Мне он показался достаточно удобным.

Comment: А совсем реальные проблемы с UTF-8.

Comment: Да, точно: Unicode бывает разный. А есть еще такое мракобесие, как MBCS (Multibyte character sets)